# Rails: is there a difference between 'references :foo' and 'integer :foo_id'?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, migration

When I use `references :foo` in a migration, the column that's generated is called `foo_id`.  Is there actually any difference between doing `references :foo` and just doing `integer :foo_id`?  Maybe something going on under the hood to enforce the relationship at the database level?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The result is the same for your specific case; you are correct. But `references` allows for a `:polymorphic => true` option which will automatically create the `foo_type` column as a string in the table.

Semantically, `references` is better if you are trying make your migrations better reflect the relations between tables in the database.

Answer (score 2):

@Mike's answer nicely explains the meaning of `references`. However, it's often better not to couple your migrations too closely to your AR associations. In particular, you can get in to all kinds of pickle when it comes to deploying your app if you run your migrations before updating the app from version control, for instance. It's not a big deal until it bites you :-)

Comment: so are you suggesting that references can be dangerous?  Can you give an example of what kind of pickle it might get me into?

Comment: Typically this can lead to issues if your migrations and model-code updates aren't in the same version control commit, or for example if you change your mind about the association later and need to update a  machine that's too far behind the curve of your development. So you'd have migration1 that uses `references` and so determines the foreign key name from the AR model associations. Later you decide to undo that migration with a new one and also remove the association from your code. Now, any machine whose schema is 2 generations old can't run the migrations because the association has gone.

Comment: I know that's kind of convoluted. I shouldn't worry about it until it actually hurts you :-)