# How to destroy a record while a record in another model is associated to it?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, associations

I have a standard has_many belongs_to association. Now I would like to destroy the record within the `Organization` model and keep the `Transaction` record. But this is not allowed: `organization_id` would be `nil` in the `Transaction` model.

How can I destroy the Organization record while keeping the Transaction record?

Organization model:

```
has_many   :transactions, inverse_of: :organization
```

Transaction model:

```
belongs_to :organization, inverse_of: :transactions
```

Transaction migration file:

```
t.references  :organization,  foreign_key: true
```

Comment: when you say not allowed, who is not allowing it?  A validation?  Can you give a sample of the error you are getting when you try to destroy.  Normally AFAIK you can destroy parents, and children will not be destroyed unless you explicitly specify that behavior

Comment: I get the following error: `ActiveRecord::InvalidForeignKey: PG::ForeignKeyViolation: ERROR:  update or delete on table "organizations" violates foreign key constraint "fk_rails_6807b11179" on table "transactions" DETAIL: Key (id)=(21) is still referenced from table "transactions".`. I have no validations in the `Transaction` model.

Comment: Perhaps it's a matter of keeping the `transaction` record but deleting the `organization_id` value of the record? Perhaps I should then not destroy using `@organization.destroy` but in a way that automatically removes the connection?

Comment: can you just use a normal id instead of references?  sorry I missed that.

Comment: The thing is I really use the reference. I now do have it working if before destroy I first do: `if @organization.transactions.any?` ; `@organization.transactions.each do |transaction|` ; `transaction.update_columns(organization_id: nil)` ; `end` ; `end`. But I'm not sure if this is the appropriate way to go...

Comment: I have never used references, but found this:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4736879/rails-is-there-a-difference-between-references-foo-and-integer-foo-id article on SO.   You code slice seems about right... I don't think you need to the transactions.any? since it will always return a (possibly) empty collection.  Seems like a lot of work for rails... So hopefully somebody will answer and educate us all!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove `foreign_key` constraint from your migration file:

```
t.references  :organization,  foreign_key: true
```